# How can I find out what chip is used in USB <-> Serial (RS232) converter from FTDI?

Tags: windows, usb, serial-port, device-manager, chipset

I have an USB <-> RS232 converter with no designation of producer on it. After plugging it into USB port on Windows Vista 64bit computer I chose an option to automatically find and install drivers from Windows Update site. Drivers (for *USB Serial Converter* and *USB Serial Port*) were successfully installed. In Device Manager, in section Universal Serial Bus controllers in context menu for USB Serial Converter in the field Manufacturer there's FTDI.

How can I find out which type of chip (I guess it's one of those listed at http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs.htm) is used in my converter?

EDIT

Hardware Id is USB\VID_0403&PID_6001&REV_0400

ChipGenius reports this

> Device Name: +USB Serial Converter
>
> PnP Device ID: VID = 0403 PID = 6001 Serial Number: FTDIC6JT Revision:
>   (Information not returned)
>
> Device Type: Standard USB device - USB2.0 Full-Speed (USB1.1)
>
> Chip Vendor: (No match record) Chip Part-Number: (No match record)
>
> Product Vendor: USB Product Model: Serial Converter
>
> Tools on Web: (N/A)

Comment: Is this strictly for curiosity's sake, or is there a pragmatic reason why you need to care?

Comment: I need to know the chipset so that I could find out what's voltage on serial side. I'd like to use this cable as JTAG cable to connect with Linksys WRT300N and WRT350N routers and debrick them. That's why it has to be 3,3V and not 5V.

Comment: Its a FTDI chip, not sure which one though, you may never figure that out...http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=3670173&chp=0&FV=fff40038,fffc0300

Answer (score 3):

[Try USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to get the vendor ID, then look it up on a vendor list [here](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) or [here](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids)

.
[image]

[Or use Device manager](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/) to find the vendor ID

.

There is also a utility called [chip genius referred to on this page](http://agnipulse.com/2010/03/chipgenius-and-usbdeview-usb-information-tools/)
.

[image]

Comment: Vendor ID is 0403 (see my update to the question) but neither of the above tools is able to tell what product (by name) it is much less what chipset is used.

Answer (score 2):

It appears there's no reliable way to find out what chipset is used. I wrote to FTDI's support giving VID and PID and they replied it's FT232B chipset. However, when I proposed to put mapping from VID,PID to chipset on their site Gordon Lunn from FTDI replied

> VID/PID does not guarantee a chip type or how it is used.  Customers
>   can change these parameters in an EEPROM.

Much less one can find out what settings were applied; when I asked

> Is it possible to know voltage level (3,3V or 5V)?

Gordon replied

> Not without physically measuring them.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source library -- libftdi [1] -- that can read the chip eeprom and decode the chip type from it's values, but this assumes no one messed with the eeprom data.

The eeprom has some extra IDs on it, and the library knows how to map those IDs to the right chip.
Off course this assumes the eeprom was not modified latter after the factory release, but for the general case this doesn't happen, so maybe it's enough for you.

[1] http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/